# How do I query the existence of array with Odata

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a web api and doing project with it. In my some football matches there are BettingInfo array and that includes the ratios for the match.

```
-Round{}
-BettingInfo{
  -DrawCode
  -HWin
  -Awin
  -Draw}
-Stage{}
```

In my application, i want to list the matches which has BettingInfo and which doesn't have.

Is it possible the send request to my web api, to check existence of BettingInfo in match array or not ?

If i can query that, i will be able to list the matches which are on betting games or not.

If you say, send the request to Web Api and get the whole arrays and check with C# after that, can you show me the way for it ?

Thank you very much. Waiting your answers with four-eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try,

`~Matches?$filter=BettingInfo ne null`

assuming you have the QueryableAttribute on the action.